# Quick four liners

Tags: riddle, wordplay

*Perhaps the most famous of all,

I was killed a century ago.

My fate is well known to all:

What bore me, hardened, killed me.*

*Named for an African province,

And speedy as I could be.

I held the record both ways

For over twenty turns.*

*Named for another old province,

I was killed a century ago.

My fate is well known to all:

It changed the course of history.*

*The second of my name,

And the last one still around.

Change one lady's name

To get my predecessor.*

---

Who are we?

> Each verse gives a different answer, but they're all connected as indicated by the title.

**Edit:** "an African province" in the third verse now changed to "another old province". Apologies for the error!

Comment: Nice pun in the title!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are talking about

> Famous ships: all 4 are liners like the question title suggests

Verse 1:

> Titanic, most famous ship, destroyed by an iceberg

Verse 2:

> Mauretania, holding the blue Ribbon for 20 years, west- and eastbound Atlantic speed record

Verse 3:

> Sinking of the Lusitania and attack on Sussex was a turning point in WW1. Lusitania was named after a Roman province located in Portugal and Spain

Verse 4:

> Queen Mary 2, famous liner. As far as I know, only active ship referring to a British queen.

Comment: You beat me there by seconds! Well done

Comment: Re. verse 3, my apologies. I read an article too hastily: seeing that the Lusitania was named after a region just north of Mauretania, I assumed this was still in Africa, not realising that Mauretania wasn't in the same place as the modern country Mauritania.

Comment: Yes rand al'thor, i recognized that all the ships are liners^^

Comment: The title was supposed to make people think of four-liner riddles rather than four ocean liners :-P Did it work?

Comment: To be honest, i came to the solution by verse 2. 1 and 4 was easy then, only 3 gave me some trouble so that i needed to do some research (because of the african province ;)). I did not recognize the trick with the title, only some minutes after posting the solution the wordplay liners came into my head. i edited the answer now,very nice riddle.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure they're all:

> Ships

1(very sure):

> The Titanic. Very famous, sank in 1912 (approximately a century ago), and was borne by water, which, hardened, becomes the notorious iceberg

3(unsure):

> I want to say the [Lusitania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Lusitania), but I can't find a similarly named African province

4(not entirely sure):

> [The Queen Mary 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Queen_Mary_2), possibly

Comment: Hm, who was faster?^^

Comment: @kl78 You, by about 20 seconds

Comment: k, thx, just luck that i was typing faster ;)

Comment: Re. verse 3, my apologies. I read an article too hastily: seeing that the Lusitania was named after a region just north of Mauretania, I assumed this was still in Africa, not realising that Mauretania wasn't in the same place as the modern country Mauritania. I hope this didn't delay you too long! Both you and @kl78 get +1's, of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to work on the whole thing right now, but here's a contribution:

> [Wyndham Halswelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wyndham_Halswelle) was a famous athlete who died in 1915 (a century ago). The circumstances of his death were well documented and he is still remembered.

Comment: Sorry, better luck next time!